# How can I identify DB error?

Tags: error, groups, smartgroups

Suddenly an error appeared out of nowhere when managing groups.

> "Count data for smart groups is not currently calculated. You may click Update >Smart Groups to generate it. Be aware this can cause significant server load." *(screenshot 1)*

When I try to **Update Smart Group Count** or click on *Contacts* of any group, there is the error:

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
>
> DB Error: unknown error
>
> Return to home page.
>
> *(screenshot 2)*

Meanwhile, the database is NOT down. I can access contacts through search.

What could have happened? Where do I start looking for solutions?

**CiviCRM 4.7.14. on Drupal 7.52**

### [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`civicrm_group_contact_cache` table for some reason has exceeded auto-increment value limit (2^32).

This is possible because of nature of this table - caching, adding, removing items.

Solution is to drop auto-increment value to beginning:

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_group_contact_cache AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Detailed instructions are available in the ["More detailed errors"](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#debugging) section of the troubleshooting guide.  In short: Either turn on debugging AND backtrace, which will give you a more detailed error; or view the appropriate errors in your CiviCRM log.

If you need help interpreting those errors, I suggest opening a new question here.  It's also a good practice to paste the text of the error instead of (or in addition to) a screenshot of the error - it makes it easier for others to search, and easier for someone to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

You will find more information on the cause of error you are getting in civicrm log files. The location may vary of log files based on the CMS you are using. Typically location of log files for following CMS's are as follows:

**Drupal**: sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog

**Wordpress**: Location is based on civicrm version, can be found at one of the following locations:

- wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog
- wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog